# vue.js json object array as data

Tags: json, ajax, vuejs2

aye folks!

I'm currently learning to do stuff with `vue.js`. unfortunately i'm stuck atm. what i want to do is sending a request to my sample API which responds with a simple json formatted object.
I want to have this object as data in my component – but it doesn't seem to do that for whatever reason.

Ofc i tried to find a solution on stackoverflow but maybe i'm just blind or this is just like the code other people wrote. i even found [this example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/commits.html) on the official vue website but they're doing the same thing as i do .. i guess?

btw. When i run the `fetchData()` function in a separate file it does work and i can access the data i got from my API. no changes in the code .. just no vue around it. i'm really confused right now because i don't know what the mistake is.

code:

```
var $persons = [];
```

and inside my component:

```
data: {

  persons: $persons,
  currentPerson: '',
  modal: false

},


created: function() {

  this.fetchData()

},


methods: {

  fetchData: function () {

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest()

    ajax.open('GET', 'http://api.unseen.ninja/data/index.php')
    ajax.onload = function() {
      $persons = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText)
      console.log($persons[0].fname)
    }
    ajax.send()

  }

},

[...]
```

link to [the complete code](https://pastebin.com/waFeu0E6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that the `onload` callback is actually firing. If the GET request causes an error, `onload` won't fire. (In your case, the error is CORS-related, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28848096/2334849) suggested by @Pradeepb).

Second, you need to reference the `persons` data property directly, not the `$persons` array that you initialized `persons` with.

It would look like this (inside your `fetchData` method):

```
var self = this;
ajax.onload = function() {
  self.persons = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText)
  console.log($persons[0].fname)
}
```

Comment: I tried it that way before but it doesn't work. I still get no output.
I think that the ajax.onload function doesn't even fire. (added some consolte logs and the one inside this function doesn't show up.)

Comment: You're sure that `ajax.responseText` is valid JSON?

Comment: @AndreasGrafen are you sure that above suggestion not working? Check this [out](https://jsfiddle.net/ph7w4j4h/). It works fine. If you find it not working, then you must be getting some error in networks tab.

Comment: I'm sure that it's valid json, yes.

The fiddle doesn't work for me either. All i see is blank space.
http://i.epvpimg.com/8Trmbab.png

Comment: The fiddle didn't work for me either. But that was because of a network error. Are you experiencing a network error?

Comment: @thanksd nope. status code 200 for every request i'm sending – including the api request. :/

Comment: Wherever you're seeing the 200 response should also include the response data. What does that look like?

Comment: You both got the error in console? `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.unseen.ninja/data/index.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.` ??

Comment: If you get the error as above, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28848096/2334849) solution. Then JSFIDDLE will work.

Comment: @thanksd the repsonse i get is the data array the api generates: http://i.epvpimg.com/zqJ4gab.png

Comment: And you're not getting a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` error in the console? Does this fiddle alert you? https://jsfiddle.net/ph7w4j4h/1/

Comment: i just downloaded chrome to check if the solution Pradeebb provided does help with jsfiddle. It does work with the plugin and i also get an alert with your fiddle. I guess i know what the problem is now. I'll have a look into cors and set it up on the server. o:

Comment: phew. Everything does work now. I'm so glad this site exists. No way i would have figured that out by myself. Thank you very much guys! <3