# Vue.js - export and load data as JSON

Tags: json, vue.js, model

I am working on an [HTML Poster Generator](https://github.com/AmmanVMS/event-poster-generator) using Vue.js. I would like to save all the data as JSON and load **all the data** again from JSON.

I thought that this would be straight forward but the way I searched (maybe new to Vue.js) I did not find a way to load and save **the whole data** object. That would be `this`?

I would like something like this:

```js
export default Vue.extend({
  // ...
  computed: {
    getDataAsJSON() {
      return JSON.stringify(this);
    },
    setDataAsJSON(data) {
      this.data = JSON.parse(data);
    }
  }
```

I will investigate further. Answers welcome.

Research:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/46056289/1320237
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/65151532/1320237

Answer (score 0):

```
...
    getDataAsJSON() {
      return JSON.stringify(this.data);
                                  
    },
...
```

Comment: `this.data` seems `undefined` to me. Do you have a link to documentation?

Comment: You need to define data, then. In the data object. https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#data